# Error in compiling bochs collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status,handlers-chaining speedups are not supported with internal debugger or gdbstub yet

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, bochs

I've tried to compile bochs in Ubuntu22.04LTS but I met some problem.
Bochs source code version is 2.7
the configure file as follow:
[image]

there is a warning and two Error:

- configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-disasm

but I don't think this warning is the cause of compiling failure

- ERROR: handlers-chaining speedups are not supported with internal debugger or gdbstub yet
- collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [Makefile:180: bochs] Error 1

For the first error, I've looked at the bochs/configure.in(https://github.com/ipxe/bochs/blob/master/configure.in) and found following code:

```
if test "$bx_debugger" = 1 -a "$speedup_handlers_chaining" = 1; then
  speedup_handlers_chaining=0
  echo "ERROR: handlers-chaining speedups are not supported with internal debugger or gdbstub yet"
fi

if test "$bx_gdb_stub" = 1 -a "$speedup_handlers_chaining" = 1; then
  speedup_handlers_chaining=0
  echo "ERROR: handlers-chaining speedups are not supported with internal debugger or gdbstub yet"
fi
```

I think the error has something to do with interal debugger but I have no idea how to fix it.

For the second error, I've tried adding `-lz -lrt -lm -lpthread` in MakeFile but it doesn't work.
Tried add `--disable-readline` in configure file but it doesn't work as well.
If u have any other solution or thought on this, please comment.

Thanks a lot. >.<

Comment: Hi, guys, I switched Ubuntu22.04 to 20.04 and bochs compiled successfully. I've tried to solve this for the last couple of days and it really bothers me. This is a link[https://www.cnblogs.com/lqerio/p/11654617.html] that contains most of the solutions when error occurs compiling bochs. It's written in Chinese but u can go through just by looking at the pictures.

Comment: Now I think the reason perhaps has something something to do with binutils(GNU Binary Utilities,it links asm and header or something like that).I think perhaps I used sudo to compile binutils and it makes bochs unable to use interal debugger while compling.